# Multiple arguments with jetpack compose navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

How do I declare a navigation route with multiple navigation arguments? I've checked the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost), and [all](https://www.rockandnull.com/jetpack-compose-navigation/) [of](https://proandroiddev.com/android-jetpack-compose-navigation-1cdfc488b891)  [these](https://laptrinhx.com/android-jetpack-compose-navigation-4267915112/) articles (which seem to simply reiterate what the documentation says), and I could only find examples of routes with one argument.

Here's what I have:

```kotlin
composable(
  route = "createExercise/{exerciseId}",
  arguments = listOf(navArgument("exerciseId") { type = NavType.IntType })
) { backStackEntry ->
  CreateExerciseScreen(
    exerciseId = backStackEntry.arguments!!.getInt("exerciseId"),
  )
}
```

Here's what I want:

```kotlin
composable(
  route = "createExercise/{exerciseId},{workoutId}",
  arguments = listOf(
    navArgument("exerciseId") { type = NavType.IntType },
    navArgument("workoutId") { type = NavType.IntType },
  )
) { backStackEntry ->
  CreateExerciseScreen(
    exerciseId = backStackEntry.arguments!!.getInt("exerciseId"),
    workoutId = backStackEntry.arguments!!.getInt("workoutId"),
  )
}
```

I arbitrarily chose a comma-seperated syntax for the example above in place of the real syntax which I am looking for.

So, my question is: **When declaring a navigation route, what's the correct syntax for multiple arguments? (And what about optional arguments?)**

Comment: "Here's what I want" -- what specifically is wrong with it? Assuming that you tried it, what are the specific symptoms? The Navigation for Compose DSL seems to be based on the original Navigation DSL, and for [deep links](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl#deep), they show multiple arguments. Personally, I would guess it is based on path segments, so `createExercise/{exerciseId}/{workoutId}`, which happens to line up with the deep link syntax.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As per the docs:

> You can think of it as an implicit deep link that leads to a specific destination.

So it follows the same conventions as any other [implicit deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit) and conventions of RESTful URLs on the web, which would generally use a `/` to separate different arguments to form the path of the URL - this covers the required arguments:

```
createExercise/{exerciseId}/{workoutId}
```

As per the [optional arguments documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#optional-args) that path of required arguments can be followed by any number of optional arguments in the form of one or more query parameters:

```
createExercise/{exerciseId}/{workoutId}?setNumber={setNumber}&repNumber={repNumber}
```

Comment: +1 To be fair, while the use of `&` to separate multiple optional arguments is quite natural, this usage doesn't seem to actually be shown anywhere in the official docs.

Comment: For people looking for multiple optional arguments while navigating:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68747550/3283350

Answer (score 10):

Here is an elaborated code for passing multiple arguments

```
// Declaring multiple arguments placeholders 
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "profile/{userId}/{username}/{address}") {       // or startDestination = "home" 

    composable(
        "profile/{userId}/{username}/{address}",                    // declaring placeholder in String route 
        arguments = listOf(                                         // declaring argument type 
            navArgument("userId") { type = NavType.IntType },
            navArgument("username") { type = NavType.StringType },
            navArgument("address") { type = NavType.StringType }
        )
    ) { backStackEntry -> 

        // Extracting exact values and passing it to Profile() screen 
        val userId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("userId")
        val username = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("username")
        val address = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("address")

        Profile(navController, userId, username, address) 
    }
}
```

To pass exact values while performing navigation use this code

```
navController.navigate("profile/24/sriyanksid/India")       
// userId = 24, username = "sriyanksid", address = "India"
```